# C# AES Encryption Memory usage

Tags: c#, encryption, memory-leaks, .net-core

I have a question regarding the memory usage with a hybrid implementation of RSA and AES encryption algorythms. I have written a simple console program (.net core and C# 8.0 beta) that generates a random certificate and encrypts/decrypts a file. Execution times seem to be fine.

Times measured with 1000 iterations

- 230 KB file takes ~2 ms
- 28 MB file takes ~150 ms
- 92 MB file takes ~500 ms

The problem seems to be the memory usage. With the 230 KB file the program uses ~20 MB. With the 28 MB file the program uses ~490 MB. The 92 MB file spikes up to 2 GB and uses ~1.8 GB memory.

Are these numbers considered "normal" usage or is there an issue with my code?

This is my implenemtation for the AES encryption

```
static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    // Salt not modified for sample
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = 256;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    using ICryptoTransform csTf = AES.CreateEncryptor();
    using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, csTf, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
    cs.Close();
    return ms.ToArray();
}

static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    // Salt not modified for sample
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = 256;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    using ICryptoTransform csTf = AES.CreateDecryptor();
    using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, csTf, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
    cs.Close();
    return ms.ToArray();
}

static string EncryptString(string text, string password)
{
    byte[] baEncrypted = new byte[GetSaltLength() + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text)];

    Array.Copy(GetRandomBytes(), 0, baEncrypted, 0, GetSaltLength());
    Array.Copy(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), 0, baEncrypted, GetSaltLength(), Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text));

    return Convert.ToBase64String(AES_Encrypt(baEncrypted, SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))));
}

static string DecryptString(string text, string password)
{
    byte[] baDecrypted = AES_Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(text), SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));

    byte[] baResult = new byte[baDecrypted.Length - GetSaltLength()];

    Array.Copy(baDecrypted, GetSaltLength(), baResult, 0, baResult.Length);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(baResult);
}

static byte[] GetRandomBytes()
{
    byte[] ba = new byte[GetSaltLength()];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(ba);
    return ba;
}

static int GetSaltLength()
{
    return 8;
}
```

Calling the methods and iterating the calls

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest("cn=random_cert", RSA.Create(4096), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    X509Certificate2 certificate = certificateRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2));

    String data = File.ReadAllText(@"PATH TO FILE");

    Int64 AESenc, RSAenc, AESdec, RSAdec;

    List<Int64> aesEncTime = new List<Int64>();
    List<Int64> aesDecTime = new List<Int64>();
    List<Int64> rsaEncTime = new List<Int64>();
    List<Int64> rsaDecTime = new List<Int64>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        encryptData(ref certificate, ref data, out AESenc, out RSAenc, out AESdec, out RSAdec);
        aesEncTime.Add(AESenc);
        aesDecTime.Add(AESdec);
        rsaEncTime.Add(RSAenc);
        rsaDecTime.Add(RSAdec);

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine($"data.Length:\t{data.Length:n0} b");
        Console.WriteLine($"UTF8 Bytes:\t{Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(data):n0} b");

        Console.WriteLine($"Loop:\t\t{i + 1}");

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"|AES Enc|Avg: {aesEncTime.Average():0000.00} ms|Max: {aesEncTime.Max():0000.00} ms|Min: {aesEncTime.Min():0000.00} ms|");
        Console.WriteLine("|-------|---------------|---------------|---------------|");
        Console.WriteLine($"|AES Dec|Avg: {aesDecTime.Average():0000.00} ms|Max: {aesDecTime.Max():0000.00} ms|Min: {aesDecTime.Min():0000.00} ms|");
        Console.WriteLine("|-------|---------------|---------------|---------------|");
        Console.WriteLine($"|RSA Enc|Avg: {rsaEncTime.Average():0000.00} ms|Max: {rsaEncTime.Max():0000.00} ms|Min: {rsaEncTime.Min():0000.00} ms|");
        Console.WriteLine("|-------|---------------|---------------|---------------|");
        Console.WriteLine($"|RSA Dec|Avg: {rsaDecTime.Average():0000.00} ms|Max: {rsaDecTime.Max():0000.00} ms|Min: {rsaDecTime.Min():0000.00} ms|");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
        // Moving GC.Collect outside of the for-loop increases the memory usage
        GC.Collect();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void encryptData(ref X509Certificate2 certificate, ref String data, out Int64 AESenc, out Int64 RSAenc, out Int64 AESdec, out Int64 RSAdec)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    String hash = getSha256(ref data);

    stopwatch.Start();

    String encryptedData = EncryptString(data, hash);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    AESenc = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    stopwatch.Restart();

    String encryptedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.GetRSAPublicKey().Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));

    stopwatch.Stop();

    RSAenc = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    stopwatch.Restart();

    String decryptedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey().Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedKey), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));

    stopwatch.Stop();

    RSAdec = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    stopwatch.Restart();

    String decryptedData = DecryptString(encryptedData, decryptedKey);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    encryptedData = null;
    decryptedData = null;

    AESdec = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

static String getSha256(ref String value)
{
    String hash = String.Empty;
    Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
    using SHA256Managed sHA256Managed = new SHA256Managed();
    Byte[] hashData = sHA256Managed.ComputeHash(data);
    foreach (Byte item in hashData)
    {
        hash += $"{item:x2}";
    }
    return hash;
}
```

The code can be executed without any external resources (excluding a file to be encrypted).

Comment: The leaks are caused by the code. `hash += $"{item:x2}";` is a string leak. Each string operation creates a *new* temporary string. Use a StringBuilder instead. Adding items to lists can also waste memory. Lists store data in buffers. When these run out, the allocate a new buffer with double the size then copy the data over. Specify the `capacity` parameter in their constructor to create a big-enough buffer just once. The same happens with `MemoryStream`s. They are just Stream Wrappers over a buffer.

Comment: As for benchmarking, use [BencharkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) instead of a Stopwatch and manually checking memory usage. It runs each case multiple times to calculate meaningful averages *and* collects memory usage, allocations and garbage collection statistics. This will tell you what those MBs are

Comment: As for the C# 8 tag, this isn't really a C# 8 question. The code can be improved by several new .NET Core features though, like Span<> and buffer pooling. Instead of manipulating strings and generating new temporary strings, you could use `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. Instead of creating new `byte[]` buffers on each run, you could "rent" a big-enough buffer from a [MemoryPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=netstandard-2.1) and put it back once you're done.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the part you mentioned is just used for creating a hash. This is used as key for the aes encryption. I have replaced this with `stringBuilder.Append($"{item:x2}");` and the memory usage stayed the same.

Comment: Use BenchmarkDotNet to see what's actually going on. 20MB doesn't say anything. What are those things? Are you sure you aren't measuring the leftover data from each test? There are many lines in the code that copy arrays around for example, they'll have to be GCd at some point.

Comment: When you run your test, Visual Studio's [Diagnostic Tools Window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) can display the CPU, Memory usage. I suspect you'll see an ever increasing line as objects get allocated.

Comment: Another possibility is that the *debugger* pins objects in memory during debugging, even if you build in Release configuration. Use BencharkDotNet and run the tests outside the debugger to get meaningful numbers

Comment: Nope, the memory usage goes down after each iteration. See https://i.imgur.com/Pl7ZxUV.png

Comment: As mentioned by others, it is an issue of allocations. Passing around, copying, and splitting byte arrays, all add up to the memory footprint. You should consider alternative methods that *chain* the streams.

Comment: DId you use BenchmarkDotNet? Post the results. That screen is *exactly* what one would expect from temporary object allocations by the way - lots of allocations in each run, GC'd after each execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stream the data into a fixed size buffer by reading it from a `FileStream`, then use a `CryptoStream` to create the ciphertext in a file, by putting in a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream` for output.

To decrypt, create a `CryptoStream` in front of a `FileStream` for reading, and then write the data in the buffer to a `FileStream` for writing.

If you have a byte array for the plaintext or ciphertext, or if you're using a `MemoryStream` then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: PS the salt should not be a static value, and 1000 is a way too low iteration count for most passwords.

Comment: Why am I doing it wrong if I'm using a memorystream? If I don't want unencrypted data to encrypt or vice versa in the filesystem (dumping data into the temp is still a bad idea if we're talking about encryption and privacy), then where should I place it otherwise?

Comment: You're saying that you encrypt / decrypt a file in your question. So I presume both input and output are from a file? In that case, where is the confusion? If you chain two streams you first encrypt and then store data in the file, in piecemeal fashion. You don't first store in a file and encrypt afterwards. So I don't see the security concerns.